# MLflow saving weights after each epoch

Tags: keras, mlflow

I have been testing some small examples with MLflow tracking but for my usecase I would like to have the weights saved after each epoch. 
Sometimes I kill the runs before they are completely finished (I cannot use earlystopping), but what I experience now is that the weights do not get saved to the tracking ui server.
Is there a way to do this after each epoch?

Comment: Is there a function in keras to call out the weights at each epoch and return them as an object in memory?

Comment: Yes, keras has the callback "modelcheckpoint" which saves the model's weights after each epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the weights to disk and then log them as an artifact.  As long as the checkpoints/weights are saved to disk, you can log them with `mlflow_log_artifact()` or `mlflow_log_artifacts()`.  From the [docs](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#logging-functions),

> **mlflow.log_artifact()** logs a local file or directory as an artifact,
>   optionally taking an artifact_path to place it in within the run’s
>   artifact URI. Run artifacts can be organized into directories, so you
>   can place the artifact in a directory this way.
>
> **mlflow.log_artifacts()** logs all the files in a given directory as
>   artifacts, again taking an optional artifact_path.